# Unable to access props during React.cloneElement after upgrade to 17.0.2

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use React.cloneElement to override the default styles fr `Text` in `react-native`. Below is my implementation:

```
const React = require('react')
const { Platform, Text } = require('react-native')
const colorThemes = require('galarm-config').colorThemes

const defaultFontProperties = {
  ...Platform.select({
    android: {
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      fontSize: 16
    },
    ios: { fontSize: 16 }
  })
}

const oldRender = Text.render
if (oldRender) {
  Text.render = function (...args) {
    const origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args)
    const colorScheme = origin.props.colorScheme
    console.tron.log('text color scheme', colorScheme, origin.props.children)
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
      style: [
        defaultFontProperties,
        { color: colorThemes.getColorTheme(colorScheme).textColor },
        origin.props.style
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

I have been using it successfully for quite some time. I recently updated to `react-native` `0.66` after which the below code stopped working. The issue is that the `colorScheme` prop is  read as `undefined` on line 19.

Below is how the `colorScheme` is set

```
<Text colorScheme={'dark'}>
  {'Some text'}
</Text>
```

I am not sure if something has changed in `react` `17.0.2` which causes the `colorScheme` prop to be not set. I have run it in debugger and of course the `colorScheme` prop is not set but I don't know how to debug this further.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something should have changed in react/react-native internals that filters out custom props in the rendered node(`origin`). However, you can still access all the props you pass via the args since the first one corresponds to the props. You can do this instead

```
    const props = args[0];
    const colorScheme = props.colorScheme;
```

**UPDATE**

as for your second issue, try changing the order in the styles array to apply the overrides last

```
      style: [
        defaultFontProperties,
        origin.props.style,
        { color: colorThemes.getColorTheme(colorScheme).textColor }
      ]
```

setting the color this way will force it even when you explicitly set the color when using the `Text` component, you may want to check if the style prop comes with a color and set that instead of the `textColor` from the theme

```
const propsStyle = props.style ? StyleSheet.flatten(props.style) : {};
...
        {
          color:
            propsStyle.color || colorThemes.getColorTheme(colorScheme).textColor,
        },
```

Comment: I was able to access the props using the args[0] which is great but the custom color is still not applied on the text element on changing the color theme. Looks like the `cloneElement` API is not merging the two styles.

Comment: I will try to add a reproducible example for this.

Comment: @VarunGupta, I updated my answer. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I am having a strange problem where the styles applied in the `React.cloneElement` are not getting applied. I have added logs in the implementation and verify that we are resolving to the right text color. When I print the style of the resulting element, even that is set to the right value but somehow the text is always shown in black. Your answer however regarding get the props helped, so I am marking it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If, by colorScheme you mean (dark/light) mode, you can grab it directly from the appearance module:

```
import {Appearance } from 'react-native';
const theme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
```

so your code should work like this:

```
    const React = require('react')
    const { Platform, Text, Appearance } = require('react-native')
    const colorThemes = require('galarm-config').colorThemes


    const defaultFontProperties = {
    ...Platform.select({
        android: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 16
        },
        ios: { fontSize: 16 }
    })
    }

    const oldRender = Text.render
    if (oldRender) {
    Text.render = function (...args) {
        const origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args)
        const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme(); // either 'light' or 'dark'
        console.tron.log('text color scheme', colorScheme, origin.props.children)
        return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [
            defaultFontProperties,
            { color: colorThemes.getColorTheme(colorScheme).textColor },
            origin.props.style
        ]
        })
    }
    }
```

otherwise i don't know

Comment: The color theme can be set by the user as well. So, I can't read it from the Appearance.